# Safari Flexbox: Navigation doesn't get height from children if content is too high

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have the following `HTML` structure for my application:

```
body
  viewport
    navbar
    container
      content
    footer
```

`viewport:`

```
min-height: 100vh;
max-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

`navbar/header:`

```
background: #fff;
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 20;
align-items: flex-start;
```

`container:`

```
flex-grow: 1;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

My problem exists only in `Safari`, so that when the `content` is higher than the view itself, it overlaps with the `header/navbar` and `footer` and suddenly the `header/navbar` doesn't inherit the height of it's children elements.

Example:

[image: good case]

[image: bad case]

I had a look at flexbugs and tried to give `flex: 1 1 0`, `flex: auto`, `height:100%` and so on but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding `min-height: fit-content;` to the header and footer stylesheet.